# Compute the measure of a constant function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I understand measurable sets. Like: "The measure of an interval is its length." "The measure of a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}$ is multiplying each of the interval's lengths." "The measure of a countable set is zero." "The measure of the Cantor set is zero"

I am confused about how to compute the measure of a function.

A function is measurable if, for every $a \in \mathbb{R} $, the set $\{x : f(x) > a\}$ is measurable (or there are equivalent definitions).

A proposition says: Constant functions are measurable, and you prove it by taking an $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and an interval $(a, \infty)$  and checking that the preimage of $f$ is measurable. And there are other theorems of course, about measurable functions, like "continuous functions are measurable", "sum, or multiplication of measurable functions is measurable."

But these theorems don't tell me (or I am not seeing it), how to compute the particular measure of a function, in case it is measurable.

For example, what is the measure of a constant function. How to compute it?

Thanks

Comment: Remember that mathematical terms mean exactly what their definition says, not what your knowledge of English suggests they should mean. The rules of ordinary English suggest that, if something is measurable, then we should be able to assign a measure to it. But that's simply not the case for functions.  (It is the case for sets in many, but not quite all, contexts.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function being measurable has its own definition (which you have given), but does not require any concept of "the measure of a function", and indeed this is not defined.

To show the constant function $f=c$ is measurable, observe that $\{x:f(x)>a\}$ is either the empty set or the full space, depending on the particular value of $a$.